# Azure RBAC Role to Publish and Mange APPS

Tags: azure, rbac

I have a requirement where i need to give developers

1. The ability to create and publish apps in Azure
2. Manage the secret key of the app
3. edit the Manifest of the app

Is there a built in role that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements there are three built in roles you could use.

- [Application Developer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#application-developer-permissions): Users can create and manage their "own" app registrations and service principals. When creating an app the user is automatically added as "owner" and can manage the app.
- [Application Administrator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#application-administrator-permissions): Users can create and manage ALL apps, service principals and application proxies.
- [Cloud Application Administrator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#cloud-application-administrator-permissions): Users can create and manage ALL apps and service principals (but the can NOT create or manage application proxies).

Comment: Do any of these roles allow you to manage the secret keys?